# Alarmes se perdem quando celular é desligado e ligado!

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alarmmanager

Como fazer para os alarmes não se perderem?

Ex: se eu crio um `AlarmManager` que chama um `Broadcast`, se eu reiniciar(desligar/ligar) o celular o alarme não mais é lançado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ao desligar o dispositivo os alarmes são perdidos tem de os criar novamente na altura em que o dispositivo é reiniciado.

O Android lança um Intent(`android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`) quando o reinicio é terminado.
Aproveite esse facto e registe um BroadcastReceiver para executar código quando essa situação ocorrer.

Declare o BroadcastReceiver no AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="aSuaPackage.StartUpBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Adicione a permissão:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Escreva a classe do BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class StartUpBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            // Crie aqui o alarme.
        }
    }
}
```

**Nota:**
Da forma como o receiver foi declarado ele está *enabled* e será executado sempre que o dispositivo for reiniciado.
Ele pode ser declarado "desactivado", usando `android:enabled="false"`, da seguinte forma:

```
<receiver android:name="aSuaPackage.StartUpBootReceiver"
          android:enabled="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Pode "activá-lo" depois assim:

```
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Posteriormente pode "desactivá-lo" assim:

```
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Para mais informação veja, na documentação, o guia [Scheduling Repeating Alarms.](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Answer (score 3):

Faça um receiver para a action ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED, e então você pode reconfigurar alguma ação que queira quando o dispositivo é desligado/ligado.

Answer (score 2):

Apenas para complementar a resposta

Adicione a seguinte permissões:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED”/>
```

Configure seu receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=“.MeuReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```