# Alternativa ao AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-alarmmanager

Gostaria de saber uma alternativa para agendar uma notificação sem ser com o AlarmManager. 
O motivo é que quando o celular é desligado e depois ligado, a tarefa  agendado é removida.

Comment: Relacionado [Alarmes se perdem quando celular é desligado e ligado!](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19356/2541)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As "alternativas" são:

- [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler)

  Requer API Level 21 - Veja, nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/225100/2541), alternativas que correm em API Level inferior.
- [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

  Nova api incluída no novíssimo [Android Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/).
  Usa as bibliotecas de suporte, permitindo compatibilidade com versões anteriores.

Note que estas api's não substituem o AlarmManager, nomeadamente no que diz à exactidão do momento em que as tarefas são realizadas.

Se quiser usar o AlarmManager, pode resolver o problema da remoção do alarme após o desligar e ligar do celular seguindo o indicado nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/192391/2541).

Comment: No caso para mim agendar com JobSchedueler em um data especifica, pelo que vi e pesquisei eu teria que pegar a data e  transformar ela em segundo certo? ou tem um forma de passar um triggerAtMillis?

Comment: O JobSchedueler não tem *triggerAtMillis*.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que haja um equívoco no entendimento do funcionamento do `AlarmManager`. Você não precisa controlar o tempo que passou, ou o tempo que falta. A ferramenta utiliza o parâmetro `long triggerAtMillis` que é o tempo que vai executar o alarme. Este tempo é a quantidade de milisegundos desde 01-01-1970. No dia `01-07-2018 às 12:00:00` **sempre** vai ter o valor de `1530457200000` milisegundos. Quando o celular for reiniciado e mandar este valor para o alarme vai manter a mesma data. Portanto se você quiser manter o mesmo tempo de alarme mesmo com o celular desligado ou não, tudo que você precisa fazer é armazenar o **tempo** que você quer agendar novamente quando ele liga, por exemplo `01-05-2018 12:01:05`:

```
int dia, mes, ano, hora, minuto, segundo;
dia = 1; mes = 5; ano = 2018; hora = 12; minuto = 1; segundo = 5;
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,   dia);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,          mes);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,           ano);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,   hora);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,      minuto);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,     segundo);
long milisegundos = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

`milisegundos` sempre vai ter o valor de `1525186800000`. Uma ferramenta boa pra testar se puxou a data correta é usar o site [currentmillis](https://currentmillis.com/).

Comment: Pode ser que sim, testei isto no emulador, acho que é melhor testar em um telefone real.

Comment: Isso é verdade mas tome note que o alarme tem de ser registado novamente após o reinicio do celular.

Comment: isso mesmo @ramaral, é necessário setar novamente quando o aparelho inicia para agendar o mesmo horário