# Definir tempo de execução JobService Android

Tags: android

Olá, eu preciso implementar um JobService no Android.

Eu criei a classe base para um Job, mas não estou conseguindo definir um parâmetro de execução, minutos, dias horas e etc.

Não encontro exemplo, alguém já implementou e poderia me ajudar?

```
public class InformarLocalizacao extends JobService {


@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    return false;
}
```

}

O `<ervice>` foi adicionado no manifest, mas eu preciso que uma rotina seja chamada de tempo-em-tempo...

Answer (score 3):

Para lançar o JobService tem de usar o [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler) fornecendo-lhe um [JobInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo).

É o JobInfo que informa o JobScheduler quando o JobService deve ser executado.

O JobInfo define um conjunto de regras que indicam quando e quais as condições que se devem verificar para o JobService ser lançado.

O quando é indicado com `setMinimumLatency()` e `setOverrideDeadline()`, e a periodicidade com `setPeriodic()`.
São várias as condições que podem ser impostas, entre elas o dispositivo estar ou não a carregar e/ou estar a ser usado ou não.
O JobInfo é construído usando um [JobInfo.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo).

Note que o propósito do JobScheduler não é executar tarefas em tempo(data) determinado(a).

Comment: A questão é que a versão no qual eu preciso implementar é a Jelly Bean, o JobService funciona apenas a partir da da Lollipop. Existem inúmeras soluções de compatibilidade. Sabe me indicar a melhor?

Comment: Talvez o WorkManager, mas depende do que quer fazer. Veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/299957/2541)

Comment: Tente o Firebase Job Dispatcher https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android#user-content-firebase-jobdispatcher-

Comment: Deu certo com o FirebaseJobDispatcher Valeu.