# Remover a notificação "App is running in background"

Tags: android, notificação

Fiz a correção do meu app para trabalhar em background com o android 8 porem muitos clientes chegaram a desinstalar o aplicativo por causa da notificação permanente "App is running in background".
Preciso do meu Intent Service executando a cada x período sem que a notificação apareça ao usuário.

No meu Service eu tenho o seguinte código

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    Log.e("InBackground", "Serviço em background iniciado");

    Intent newIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),Service.class);
    newIntent.putExtra("comando","AtualizaInBackground");

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Atualizações em Background.", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);

        ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("")
                .setContentText("").build();
        startForeground(1, notification);
    }
    startService(newIntent);


    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Talvez ajude https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/299957/2541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir do android 8 o Google mudou uma serie de coisas envolvendo serviços no android.

Aconselho dar uma olhada na documentação pois teve varias mudanças:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Pelo que lembro de cabeça se o seu app não esta em primeiro plano o Android vai matar os serviços em x tempo (alguns segundos), o jeito mais fácil de contornar isso é do jeito que você fez exibindo uma notificação. Acabei usando esse método no meu app também, então se mais alguém tiver alguma outra alternativa é bem vindo :D